# Youtube API V3; Maximum number of videos only 50?

Tags: youtube-api

I managed to send a request to the Youtube API and get a list of videos from a channel, however it works only if the value of **maxResults** is 50 or less.

**It seems that YouTube API only returns max 50 videos.**

I found out that to get more results I need to use **pageToken** option.
But I'm not sure how to use it?

Any example or tutorials, which could help me to understand how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best resource to look is actually the documentation about [implementation of pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination).

> If additional results are available for a query, then the API response
>   will contain either a **`nextPageToken`** property, a
>   **`prevPageToken`** property, or both. Those properties' values can then be used to set the **`pageToken`** parameter to retrieve an
>   additional page of results.

I've also found [this resource](https://www.forgov.qld.gov.au/file/21896/download?token=mo1SpiZT) which is I think could be helpful to answer your questions regarding pagination.

Additional note from the provided reference:

> Note that if the list is very long it will take some time to browse
>   through it. This is because the API limits the number of results to 50
>   a page and if you want to go to the next page of results, you have to
>   repeat the call, adding a `nextPageToken` reference ID when you do so.
>   For this reason, it is important to make sure that you request the
>   `nextPageToken` reference when you make the first call and later calls
>   as well.

Comment: I've tried this, but it only ever gives me 4 pages before the `nextPageToken` returns `null`. At 50 results per page, does this just mean that the video list I am looking at (the trending videos list, in this case) only has 200 videos in it, or am I doing something wrong?